# Solving an equation that contains u and (1-u) as variables

Tags: equation-solving

How can the following equation be solved using Mathematica, as the equation contains `u` and `1-u`?

`((1 - u)^-0.3117 - 1)^0.1057 + (u^-0.0364 - 1)^-0.1057 - 2.3612 = 0`

Here the value of `u` lies between `0` and `1`. I use `FindRoot` and get `u=0.536128` as the answer, which seems to be incorrect. How can this be solved?

Comment: Please post the complete Mathematica code.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The equation is univariate since it has one variable `u`. Your answer is correct. What makes you say that it is incorrect?

Comment: I used this u=0.536128 for my further calculation and found that estimates of income inequality measures like pietra, and fridges measures show deviation from empirical values. Usually estimated values are closer to empirical values.

Comment: Plot the lhs of your equation. You'll see it has a single axis crossing and diverges to -infinity at u=0, and infinity at u=1. So it's a valid solution, and the only solution from 0 to 1. If your other estimates are off, perhaps your equation for u isn't modeling your system as well as you'd hoped.

Answer (score 3):

For equation solving there is the command "Solve". You can also give conditions like u between 0 and 1. Often Solve will rationalize the constants and let you know, but this is nothing to worry about:

```
Solve[{((1 - u)^-0.3117 - 1)^0.1057 + (u^-0.0364 - 1)^-0.1057 - 
    2.3612 == 0, 0 <= u <= 1}, u]

{{u -> 0.536128}}
```

To check if this is correct, you may use the original equation:

```
((1 - u)^-0.3117 - 1)^0.1057 + (u^-0.0364 - 1)^-0.1057 - 2.3612 /. 
 u -> 0.536127828203985`

-2.22045*10^-16
```

As you are calculating with machine numbers that are not exact, this is correct.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in two steps. First,

```
FunctionDomain[((1 - u)^-0.3117 - 1)^0.1057 + (u^-0.0364 - 1)^-0.1057 - 2.3612, u]
```

> `0 < u < 1`

Second,

```
FindRoot[(1/(1 - u)^0.3117 - 1)^0.1057 +  1/(1/u^0.0364 - 1)^0.1057 - 2.3612 == 0,{u, 0.5}]
```

> `{u -> 0.536128}`

finishes the job.